# Concatenate strings in a matrix python

Tags: python, numpy, string-concatenation

I have a matrix with strings as follows,

```
array([['', '', 'C'],
       ['A', '', 'C'],
       ['', 'B', '']], dtype='|S9')
```

I need to concatenate columns in each row to get an output similar to following,

```
array([['C'],
       ['A C'],
       ['B']])
```

The size of the matrix I need to apply this is very large. Is there something similar to column sum in python as `np.sum(matrix, axis=0)` to do this string concatenation?

Comment: Do you want the resulting `dtype` to be `|S9` or `|S27`? (And, if the former, what do you want to happen if the strings are too long to fit in `S9`?)

Comment: Meanwhile, you can use the [`np.char` functions `add`, `join`, etc.](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/routines.char.html), but the implementation of those are based on the normal Python functions. So, you really can't do much to improve performance here. They aren't `ufunc`s, so the usual rules for broadcasting regular functions over an array apply, with the usual performance caveats.

Answer (score 2):

`np.tensordot` has an example of taking advantage of operator overloading for strings (not string dtypes).  Taking that as a clue I tried the following:

```
In [678]: arr = np.array([['', '', 'C'],
     ...:        ['A', '', 'C'],
     ...:        ['', 'B', '']], dtype='U3')
     ...:
```

I'm in py3, so `U` gives a cleaner display.  `U3` dtypes don't implement `+'.  But converting the string dtype to object dtype creates an array of real Python strings:

```
In [679]: arrO=arr.astype(object)

In [681]: arrO
Out[681]: 
array([['', '', 'C'],
       ['A', '', 'C'],
       ['', 'B', '']], dtype=object)
```

Now `sum` joins the strings, in effect doing `'A'+''+'C'`, etc:

```
In [682]: np.sum(arrO, axis=1)
Out[682]: array(['C', 'AC', 'B'], dtype=object)
```

`np.char` has some functions that apply string methods to the elements of a string dtype array.  There is a `np.char.join` but it works elementwise, not across elements.

`np.split` works on array elements, but it produces lists:

```
In [690]: np.char.split(np.array(['A B C','D E F']))
Out[690]: array([list(['A', 'B', 'C']), list(['D', 'E', 'F'])], dtype=object)
```

It can be reverse with `np.char.join`:

```
In [691]: np.char.join(',',_)
Out[691]: array(['A,B,C', 'D,E,F'], dtype='<U5')
In [699]: np.char.join('',Out[690])
Out[699]: array(['ABC', 'DEF'], dtype='<U3')
```

So `join` would work if `arr` could be transformed into `np.array(list(['','','C']),..., dtype=object)`.

But before going too far down that road, I should note that the `np.char` functions can be handy, but they aren't much faster, if at all, than list comprehensions using the same string methods.